# How to wget a dynamic website? (Javascript and PHP)

Tags: javascript, php, dynamic, debian, wget

I am trying to find a way to wget a [website](https://www.sagedining.com/menus/admiralfarragutacademy).

I have tried wget, curl, and PhantomJS with no luck.
Is there any way to download this website after it loads all the menus?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`wget` and `curl` talk HTTP and show you the server responses. They do not implement a browser that executes Javascript, so they can't give you the result that you seek.

PhantomJS should work. It's a script interface for controlling a Chromium browser, complete with Javascript processing of loaded pages. You say that you tried it; ask another question and show us what you tried with PhantomJS.